# Applescript to open an application in full-screen mode?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, alfred

I'm trying to program Alfred to open my Terminal, Sublime Text, and Chrome with a workflow.

I would like for my terminal to open normally as a window, but I've been trying to get Chrome and Sublime to open full screen.

I was able to get Chrome to open up in full screen mode with:

```
on alfred_script(q)
   tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell window 1 to enter presentation mode
   end tell
end alfred_script
```

However, this did not translate to work with my Sublime Text.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do this assuming you have not changed the default keyboard shortcut for "Enter Full Screen" is simply to have System Events invoke that shortcut (⌃⌘F). As with the other approach I've seen to doing this (changing the value of `AXFullScreen`—see [mklement0's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12395536/2680007) for a thorough discussion of this method), this requires making the relevant window active.

For instance, to toggle the full-screen state of the frontmost window in Safari, run:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
end tell
```

Comment: just to add the code for the frequently used "ALT" button is not `alt down`, but `option down`

Answer (score 4):

As found here ([i need an applescript to open safari in full screen an to hide the toolbar on mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801733/i-need-an-applescript-to-open-safari-in-full-screen-an-to-hide-the-toolbar-on-ma)).  The `make new document` line prevents the `can't get window 1` error by opening a new tab if one has not previously been opened.

```
tell application "Safari"

    make new document
    
    activate

    delay 3

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"

        set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true

    end tell

end tell
```

Comment: System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process "Safari". Invalid index.

Comment: I receive the following: "Script Error: System Events got an error: Script Editor is not allowed assistive access."

Comment: It works after allowing the Script Editor to access Accessibility in System Preferences.

Comment: error "System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process \"Safari\". Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1 of process "Safari"

Comment: This is an error you get if Safari does not have a window currently open.  I have edited the answer to prevent this.