# Launching other apps in fullscreen

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, accessibility, nsworkspace

As I mentioned in the topic I am wondering if there is any way to run an app in fullscreen right from my app.

I tried to use Accessibility, but I haven't found anything that could help. I also tried to use NSWorkspace, but the result is the same. I'm stuck.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sandboxed?

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in non-sandboxed solution too.

Comment: Non-sandboxed should be relatively easy: open it, then send an event.  My gut says it won't be possible from the sandbox, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you give me more details how to send an event to other applications?

Comment: Maybe use AppleScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272353/applescript-to-open-an-application-in-full-screen-mode

Comment: Hmm, but I can't choose which instance of application will be open in fullscreen, right?

Comment: You can use AppleScript to target process IDs

Comment: Unfortunately not every application can be toggled to fullscreen with cmd + ctrl + F combination. Any other solutions?